fail connection udp server in docker
I quite new in docker and network and I have a udp servet with two ports for listen and send message and the same in the client side. The goal of this connection is they are synchronising the flags which the server is on a docker container and the client is on local host.
Here is the server code:
import socket
import time
import random


class Physical:

    def __init__(self, remote_ip, remote_port, port, t):
        self.remote_ip = remote_ip
        self.remote_port = remote_port
        self.port = port
        self.t = t
        self.tick = 0
        self.ctrl_flag = 0
        self.ctrl_url = None
        self.sw_state = 0
        self.sw_package = None
        self.receive_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.send_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.receive_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # input here
            if random.randint(0, 20) <= 3:
                self.ctrl_flag = random.randint(0, 10)
                print("in ctrl_flag {} {}".format(self.ctrl_flag, self.tick))
            else:
                print("same ctrl_flag {} {}".format(self.ctrl_flag, self.tick))

            self.receive_sync()
            # intermediary states
            self.tick += 1
            self.send_sync()
            print("new ctrl_flag {}, {}\n".format(self.ctrl_flag, self.tick))

    def send_sync(self):
        self.send_socket.sendto("{}".format(self.ctrl_flag).encode(), (self.remote_ip, self.remote_port))

    def receive_sync(self):
        data, addr = self.receive_socket.recvfrom(256)
        self.ctrl_flag = int(data)


def main():
    phy = Physical("0.0.0.0", 5555, 5556, 0)
    phy.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The client code is:
import socket
import random
import asyncio
#SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

class Twin:

    def __init__(self, remote_ip, remote_port, port, t):
        self.remote_ip = remote_ip
        self.remote_port = remote_port
        self.port = port
        self.t = t
        self.tick = 0
        self.ctrl_flag = 0
        self.ctrl_url = None
        self.sw_state = 0
        self.sw_package = None
        self.receive_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.send_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.receive_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", self.port))

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            # time.sleep(self.t)
            await asyncio.sleep(self.t)
            # input here
            if random.randint(0, 20) <= 3:
                self.ctrl_flag = random.randint(0, 10)
                print("in ctrl_flag {}, ticket {}".format(self.ctrl_flag, self.tick))
            else:
                print("same ctrl_flag {}, ticket {}".format(self.ctrl_flag, self.tick))

            self.send_sync()
            # intermediary state
            self.tick += 1
            self.receive_sync()
            print("new ctrl_flag {}, ticket {}\n".format(self.ctrl_flag, self.tick))

    def send_sync(self):
        self.send_socket.sendto("{}".format(self.ctrl_flag).encode(), (self.remote_ip, self.remote_port))

    def receive_sync(self):
        data, addr = self.receive_socket.recvfrom(256)
        self.ctrl_flag = int(data)


def main():
    twin = Twin("127.0.0.1", 5556, 5555, 2)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.call_later(time, twin.stop())
    task = loop.create_task(twin.run())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The dockerfile to build the image is:
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /Physical

COPY . /Physical

EXPOSE 5555/udp

EXPOSE 5556/udp

ENV NAME digitaltwin

CMD ["python3", "-u", "Physical.py"]


For running the image once I used this command docker run -p 5555:5550/udp -p 5556:5559/udp digitaltwin:latest the server and the client couldn't connect without any specific error but it was like they were running separatly and couldn't go forward to sync the flags.
The other command I used was forwarding the same port to the docker container docker run -p 5555:5555/udp -p 5556:5556/udp digitaltwin:latest when I tried to run the client the error was the address is allocated already.
Does anyone know how I can fix it?

It looks like, in the server code, your outbound send_socket is trying to send to the special "all interfaces" listener address 0.0.0.0, which doesn't really make sense.  It seems like the server might be running on a container-specific localhost, and the client outside a container on the host machine, so not the server process's localhost?  If you use UDP then you need Docker-specific wiring in both directions for the two processes to reach each other, but if it's possible to use TCP instead then the docker run -p option is likely enough.

@DavidMaze So in this case shall I use the internal IP address of docker instead ?

In the server code, where main() creates the Physical() object, the first parameter needs to be the address where the server sends back to the client.  If the client's not in a container then From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine? describes some ways to find this.  I'm not sure how to handle this more portably for cases like "server isn't in a container".
